# Custom user model - TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-users

I made a custom user model.

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender, mobile_number, is_active, is_admin, is_superuser):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
            gender=gender,
            mobile_number=mobile_number,
            date_joined=timezone.now,
            is_active=is_active,
            is_admin=is_admin,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender, mobile_number, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, username, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender, mobile_number, True, False, False, **extra_fields
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender, mobile_number, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, username, password, first_name, last_name, date_of_birth, gender, mobile_number, True, True, True, **extra_fields )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('user name'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDERTYPE, max_length=1)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'mobile_number']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email
    ...
    ...
```

Migrations were done successfully. However, when trying to create a superuser I am getting error like this:

```
(djangoweb) vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/djangoweb/myproject$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Email address: testme@gmail.com
User name: testme
First name: test
Last name: me
Date of birth: 1111-11-11
Gender: 1
Mobile number: 1111
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 52, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 173, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/vagrant/djangoweb/myproject/custom_user/models.py", line 72, in create_superuser
    **extra_fields
  File "/vagrant/djangoweb/myproject/custom_user/models.py", line 36, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 74, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 820, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1019, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 958, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1461, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1440, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1296, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1399, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/vagrant/Envs/djangoweb/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 93, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I think this is because of something related to datetime, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive but I'm guessing its this line:

```
user = self.model(
    #other code
    date_joined=timezone.now,
    #other code
)
```

You're passing a function as the value for date_joined instead of the actual value timezone.now(). That is the right way to do it in the model declaration you have, but I believe you need the actual value when making the object.

```
user = self.model(
    #other code
    date_joined=timezone.now(),
    #other code
)
```

Of course, since you have a default specified, you could always just leave this out completely and let the model fill in the default.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I have been a fool. Thank you so much.